# inSampleSize is not working

Tags: android

In short, I can't resize my image file (475px in height) using inSampleSize. Code as below.

Image should be reduced to 237.5 px, after the code, isn't it? But it remains unchanged, exactly same as original dimension.

Anybody can help please.

```
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "1223fdf");
URL imageUrl = new URL("http://example.com/file.jpg");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
String url = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
URL redirectURL = new URL(url);
URLConnection redirectConn = redirectURL.openConnection();
InputStream is=redirectConn.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
os.close();
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

final int REQUIRED_SIZE=200;
int height_tmp=o.outHeight; // This returns 475
int scale=1;
while(true){
    if(height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
        break;
    height_tmp/=2;
    scale*=2;
}
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize=scale; //SCALE = 2 here (checked by printing in LogCat)
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
return bmp;




public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please log bmp.getWidth() and bmp.getHeight() before returning the bitmap. What are the numbers?

Comment: your suspicion is correct, bmp.getHeight shows 238px (which is correct) ... but the file saved is 475px .. why is that please?

Comment: Because you are saving a file before scaling, so it has its original dimensions. If you want to save a scaled file you need to modify your code.

Comment: oh .. I thought it is going to modify the existing file .... so, I should save the bmp to file, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Currently you are only loading bitmap from the input stream.

Comment: thanks ... if you post as reply, I'll accept the answer ..

Comment: there is also createScaledBitmap